# How to take data range input from the user in an Excel VSTO Add-in through a textfield?

Tags: vsto, office-js, office-addins, excel-addins, excel-charts

I want to create a Bar chart on Excel Add-in, but I want to get the datarange from the user in a textfield, how can I use that value and assign it to the dataRange variable?
Here is my code:
In home.html,
`<input type="text" id="chart-range" class="right" />`
In Home.js:

```
       $("#chart-range").change(function ()
      var input = document.getElementById("chart-range");
      var value = input.options[input.selectedIndex].value;
      createBarChart();
       })
                       
   })
  function createBarChart() {
        Excel.run(function (context) {

            const sheet = context.workbook.worksheets.getItem("Sheet1");
            const salesTable = sheet.tables.getItem("Table1");
            const dataRange = salesTable.getDataBodyRange();
            let chart = sheet.charts.add("ColumnClustered", dataRange, "Auto");

            chart.setPosition("A9", "F20");
            chart.title.text = "Farm Sales Bar chart";
            chart.legend.position = "Right";
            chart.legend.format.fill.setSolidColor("white");
            chart.dataLabels.format.font.size = 15;
            chart.dataLabels.format.font.color = "black";
            let points = chart.series.getItemAt(0).points;
            points.getItemAt(0).format.fill.setSolidColor("pink");
            points.getItemAt(1).format.fill.setSolidColor("indigo");

            return context.sync();
        })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log("Error: " + error);
                if (error instanceof OfficeExtension.Error) {
                    console.log("Debug info: " + JSON.stringify(error.debugInfo));
                }
            });
    }
```

Comment: what do you mean for the "text field"? is this "text field" created in VSTO add-in?

Comment: @RaymondLu Yes, the text field is added in the VTO add-in : In home.html,
            <input type="text" id="chart-range" class="right" />

Comment: is this an active x control in the developer tab?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62966964/how-to-take-chart-target-position-as-input-from-the-user-in-an-excel-vsto-add-in/62981175

Comment: @RaymondLu I want to set the body range of the table, after taking input from the user in a textfield, after taking the range as input I want to use that to create a chart.

Comment: Does Dongqi Lv's solution work for you? she is from our team. thanks

Comment: @RaymondLu Dongqi Lv's solution works fine. Thanks.